# C# Regex to replace style HEIGHT tags

Tags: c#, html, regex

I need to replace a HEIGHT tag with MIN-HEIGHT but am struggling with excluding opening quotes from the replace.

This is my Regex:

```
[^-](height:)
```

This is my replace:

```
html = regex.Replace(html, "min-height:");
```

AS I understand it this should match 'height:' but not 'min-height:' but when I do the replace it also replaces the character immediately prior to height:.

so style="HEIGHT: becomes style=MIN-HEIGHT:

How do I maintain the opening quote in the replace but also cater for HEIGHT: being, say, the 3rd attribute of a style tag and not bumpered against the quotes (e.g. style="WIDTH: 200px; HEIGHT: 400px" ?

Example input would be:

style="HEIGHT: 500px;"
style="WIDTH: 200px; HEIGHT: 500px"
style="WIDTH: 200px;HEIGHT: 500px"

Expected output:

style="MIN-HEIGHT: 500px;"
style="WIDTH: 200px; MIN-HEIGHT: 500px"
style="WIDTH: 200px;MIN-HEIGHT: 500px"

Current output:

style=MIN-HEIGHT 500px;"
style="WIDTH: 200px;MIN-HEIGHT 500px"
style="WIDTH: 200pxMIN-HEIGHT 500px"

[Regex101 link here](https://www.regex101.com/r/pP7qT0/1)

Comment: post an example along with expected output? Is `height` a case sensitive string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?<!-)(height:)
```

Try this.Use 0 width assertion rather than capturing .See demo.The `lookbehind` will make sure there is no `-` behind `height` being captured.Use `i` modifier if `height` is `case-sensitive`

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/78